# Can anyone figure out why addEventListener on my div is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a listener to a small button like div so I can eventually change the color once clicked without having to use an actual button for different reasons. I have seen multiple people on here say that it works or should work. Is there something I am missing or is it just not possible? Just looking for answers!

It's pretty simple and I have verified the button works with the same function.

```
//this is the entire js page at the moment
var WorkingOutManager = (function () {

    this.setCounter = 1;
    this.workoutCounter = 1;

    this.workoutID = "workout" + workoutCounter + "_set" + setCounter;

    this.changeState = () => {
        //I will eventually add the code to change the state of the div
        console.log(this.workoutID);
    }

    this.currentSetButton = document.getElementById(this.workoutID).
    this.currentSetButton.addEventListener("click", this.changeState);

    return {
        changeState: changeState
    }

})();
```

```
<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <a id="banner_text_link" href="../content/home.html">Work It Out</a>
    </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div>
                <img id="page_image"
                    onclick="window.location.href='../content/home.html'"
                    src="../images/work_it_out_logo_workouts.png" alt="Work It
                    Out logo">
            </div>
            <!--Eventually, Display a Timer after pressing start -->
            <div id="current_workout">
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Pushups</div>
                    <div onclick="WorkingOutManager.changeState()"
                        class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set1">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set2">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set3">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set4">15</div>
                </div>
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Situps</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set1">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set2">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set3">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set4">TF</div>
                </div>
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Pullups</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set1">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set2">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set3">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set4">TF</div>
                </div>
                <button onclick="WorkingOutManager.changeState()"
                    id="add_exercise">COMPLETE WORKOUT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="../scripts/working_out.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
#current_workout {
    color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.workout_exercise {
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    height: 3rem;
    width: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

.set_name {
    color: #fafafa;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
    width: calc(30% - 0.4rem);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
    /* border-style: outset; */
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
}

.set_exercise {
    float: right;
    width: calc(calc(70% / 4) - 0.2rem);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.1rem;
    margin: 0 0.1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* transform: rotate(-25deg);
    text-transform: rotate(25deg); */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
    /* border-style: outset; */
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

I am not receiving any error messages when I click on the div with the onClick listener. Nothing happens at all, in fact. The button at the bottom of the "current_workout" div works properly and logs the correctly formatted "workoutID."

Answer (score 2):

It works for me if I change the '.' at the end of this line to a semicolon:

```
this.currentSetButton = document.getElementById(this.workoutID).
```

Because you're using `float: right` on `.set_exercise`, the items are listed from right to left instead of left to right. The clickable item, `workout1_set1` is at the ***right end of the row***, not the left. My guess is that you've been clicking the wrong item. I've tweaked your css to highlight the clickable item in the snippet below.

(The handler is firing twice because you've also got an `onclick` attribute on the div.)

FWIW—I'm not going to tell you how to do your thing—but I see no good reason to use `float` here (or anywhere at all, ever, really). You could achieve this layout with flexbox, grid, or a table and avoid all of the headaches that come with floats. (I don't usually advocate for tables, but one could argue that this *is* a table.)

```js
var WorkingOutManager = (function () {

    this.setCounter = 1;
    this.workoutCounter = 1;

    this.workoutID = "workout" + workoutCounter + "_set" + setCounter;

    this.changeState = () => {
        //I will eventually add the code to change the state of the div
        console.log(this.workoutID);
    }

    this.currentSetButton = document.getElementById(this.workoutID);
    this.currentSetButton.addEventListener("click", this.changeState);

    return {
        changeState: changeState
    }

})();
```

```css
#current_workout {
    color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.workout_exercise {
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    height: 3rem;
    width: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

.set_name {
    color: #fafafa;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
    width: calc(30% - 0.4rem);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
    /* border-style: outset; */
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
}

.set_exercise {
    float: right;
    width: calc(calc(70% / 4) - 0.2rem);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.1rem;
    margin: 0 0.1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* transform: rotate(-25deg);
    text-transform: rotate(25deg); */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
    /* border-style: outset; */
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

#workout1_set1 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
        <a id="banner_text_link" href="../content/home.html">Work It Out</a>
    </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div>
                <img id="page_image"
                    onclick="window.location.href='../content/home.html'"
                    src="../images/work_it_out_logo_workouts.png" alt="Work It
                    Out logo">
            </div>
            <!--Eventually, Display a Timer after pressing start -->
            <div id="current_workout">
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Pushups</div>
                    <div onclick="WorkingOutManager.changeState()"
                        class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set1">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set2">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set3">15</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout1_set4">15</div>
                </div>
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Situps</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set1">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set2">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set3">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout2_set4">TF</div>
                </div>
                <div class="workout_exercise">
                    <div class="set_name">Pullups</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set1">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set2">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set3">TF</div>
                    <div class="set_exercise" id="workout3_set4">TF</div>
                </div>
                <button onclick="WorkingOutManager.changeState()"
                    id="add_exercise">COMPLETE WORKOUT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```